# Focus goes to parent grid instead of textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have a grid with a multiple rows and row definitions.

```
<Grid x:Name="RContentGrid" Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Name="RLabelRowDefinition" Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="HeadingsRowDefinition" Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="1RowDefinition" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="2RowDefinition" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="LineRowDefinition" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="3RowDefinition" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="4RowDefinition" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="5RowDefinition" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Name="ErrorRowDefinition" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
...
```

One of the textboxes looks like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxRight1" 
    Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"
    Style="{DynamicResource g_TextInputWithLabelSmall}" 
    FontFamily="Arial Narrow" FontSize="16" />
```

The referred style looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="g_TextInputWithLabelSmall" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Helpers:ClientKeyboardController.AutoShowKeyboard" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Helpers:ClientKeyboardController.AutoHideKeyboard" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid MinHeight="35" MinWidth="55">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectedStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="CustomSelected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContentHost">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CustomUnSelected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContentHost">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF666666"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFCCCCCC"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(Brush.RelativeTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-45"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.6"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#33000000"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#33000000"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContentHost">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContentHost">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFE3001B"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContentHost">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                                        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd">
                                        <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContentHost">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFE3001B"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContentHost">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,-75,0,50" Height="Auto">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsHyphenationEnabled="True" Height="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource g_TextFieldLabel_14_100}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,2,0" Width="Auto" Opacity="0.6"><Run Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/><Run Text=" "/><Run Foreground="#88000000" Text="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}"/></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ErrorColor}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="White" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                            <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                            <RotateTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" Angle="135"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFCCCCCC" Offset="0.5"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF666666" Offset="0.5"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Template="{DynamicResource g_TextInput}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem I face is that when the user clicks the textbox on the bottom half the focus goes to the grid above. Only when the user clicks on the upper half the focus comes to the textbox.

I tried the following:
- Tried changing the row definition of the rows
- Tried changing the height of the row

What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like x:Name="textBlock" in your style template (more specifically it's parent Grid) is creating overlaps due to the negative `Margin` so as it's rendered in Z order each box is overlapping the one above it with it's hittestvisibility area.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chris W. :)

By removing the margin on the Grid I was able to solve the problem:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="Auto">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsHyphenationEnabled="True" Height="Auto" Style="{DynamicResource g_TextFieldLabel_14_100}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,2,0" Width="Auto" Opacity="0.6"><Run Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/><Run Text=" "/><Run Foreground="#88000000" Text="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}"/></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
```